# Text-Shadow transition on and off hover

Tags: css

trying to get my website to transition text-shadow on and off hover. When I use a transition without a specified property you can see font-size,color,etc transition. When specifying the text-shadow property in the transition no transition appears (currently using Chrome to test).

```
nav ul li a {
    color: white;
    transition: text-shadow 0.5s ease;
}
    
nav ul li a:hover {
    color:grey;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.23);    
}
```

Comment: you need an initial text-shadow

Comment: As per @TemaniAfif comment, try adding `2px 2px 10px transparent;` to your `nav ul li a` declaration. Now it knows what values to transition _between_.

Comment: Tried an initial text-shadow both transparent and non-transparent in the "nav ul li a" doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Zachc40 Indeed, it does seem like a rather odd instance here. Do you mind amending your question and turning your code into a snippet we can play around with? Just add a background color, reduce your CSS declaration to simple an `h1` or something and add an `h1` we can hover over. When I tried it, the expected effect is indeed not appearing.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are not being deceived by the lightness of your color? I have amended your code and made it a workable snippet, and if I change the color to something more explicit, like `red` and `yellow`, you can actually see the effect. It's pretty feint, though. It seems like adding that property to the default does indeed work.

```css
body {
    background: black;
}

h1, h2 {
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 10px red; 
    transition: text-shadow 1s ease;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}
h2 {
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 10px transparent;
}
    
h1:hover,
h2:hover {
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 10px yellow; 
}
```

```html
<h1>Hover on me for text shadow!</h1>
<h2>Hover on me for text shadow!</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add shadow and transition in both declarations

Try this css code

```
nav ul li a {
    color: white;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(255,255,255,0);
}
    
nav ul li a:hover {
    color:grey;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.23); 
    transition: 0.5s ease;   
}
```

Comment: Nice find in the comment section there, but have you tried it? When running this as an SO snippet it indeed doesn't appear to actually work.

Comment: When using transition without specifying a property, the all other properties transition on page load (color, font-size etc)

Comment: The shadow animates. The text shadow is white so it needs a dark bg. But it does animate. Yes if you just have transition it animates colour as well. Which is a nicer effect in the end. So you can add text-shadow 0.5s ease; if you want to just animate the shadow. But as mentioned with colour it's a nicer effect

Comment: Then simply add `color .4s ease` to it or something, using `all` is not recommended because you are prepping the browser to interpolate between all values, which will require more unnecessary computing power that you can avoid. It's small, but if you do this everywhere for every element you are overburdening the browser, so it's best to be explicit and steer clear of these general declarations.

Comment: with a declaration with just one extra property it wont make any difference at all. If you have a lot of extra properties then yes I agree. But with just color their is not much to compute ;) The solution however works.

Comment: The solution was nabbed from the comments, to be honest, but okay. Still, best not to assume as this is probably only a small part of a website. And since you founded a web design academy, it would be nice if you would teach your students the right things, not just the 'working' things. You are telling people this is okay, and they shouldn't walk away from this with the idea this is their catch-all solution.